# Can a FirebaseMessagingService be made a lifecyleowner?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

A Service can extend `LifecycleService` which `implements LifecycleOwner`. How to go about making a FirebaseMessagingService be one. Even if it just implements LifecycleOwner, what would it return on the overridden method `getLifecycle()` The background to why I need it is, a notification kicks off a `WorkManager` who's work is observed via `LiveData`.

Comment: Why do you need to observe the the status of the work in your service?  Usually, the observation is for user-facing parts of your codebase.

Comment: Service is responsible for showing a notification. It needs to wait for the Worker to complete the task before the notification can be built.

Comment: @Neo Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same question.

Comment: @BenjaminMenrad I ended up implementing a custom LifecycleOwner
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#implementing-lco